# Cell color changes when value changes

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlUfW.png)

I am working on a VBA program. I created a function, that counts the number of items that meet a particular result (size "Large" and food "Veg").  The function helps to count the number of items that meet the requirement and changes when i filter the according to class (e.g. p1 has 1 veg, it shows 1).

```
Function Count_items_Small_Veg() As Long

Dim i As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim wsCheck As Worksheet
Dim n As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    Set wsCheck = Application.Caller.Parent
    For Each r In wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(Col_Western).Cells
        If wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Starter) = "S" And _
                wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Dessert) = "VEGETARIAN" And r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
    Count_items_Small_Veg = i

End Function
```

**I want the program to change cell storing the value of number to grey when it reaches zero, when i filter the result. For instance i filter according to P2 and 0 orders for Large Veg. It should be greyed**

[The grey cell is desired result when cell value equals to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHrU3.png)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ChangeRng As Range

Set ChangeRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A5:G6")

Application.Volatile
For Each cell In ChangRng
If cell.Value = 0 Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show some data with expected result and explain what isn't working with the above? Somewhere in the above you need to specify Target which is the cell(s) that change otherwise nothing will be run. Looks like Target is your range ChangeRng.

Comment: You can even do that without programming, by using Conditional Markup.

Comment: Conditional Formatting, I mean. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: Hard to tell if due to formatting whether that cell in grey contains 0 or S:0. Worth showing column headers and row numbers to give some context as well. For worksheet change event see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change